# Crystal Reports total calculation of account in ledger type report

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I am developing a crystal report that is like a ledger report but it also includes the invoice details too.

lets say XYZ account ledger Report:

```
Invoice#  Details                         Debit         Credit        Balance
                       Qty rate  total
______________________________________________________________________________
1        product A       1  100    100                
                                           100$           0               100$
_______________________________________________________________________________
2        product B       2  150    300
2        product C       1  200    200
2        product D       2  100    200
                                           700$          0                2200$
_______________________________________________________________________________
                          Grand Toal      **2200$**      0$              **2200$**
```

the problem is in calculating the total when detail part contain more than one entry it calculate each detail record separately instead of total of an invoice.
what I want is

```
*Invoice#  Details                         Debit         Credit        Balance
                       Qty rate  total
______________________________________________________________________________
1        product A       1  100    100                
                                           100$           0               100$
_______________________________________________________________________________
2        product B       2  150    300
2        product C       1  200    200
2        product D       2  100    200
                                           700$          0                800$
_______________________________________________________________________________
                          Grand Toal      **800$**      0$              **800$***
```

invoice detail is in detail section of report and debit, credit is in group of invoice by Invoice ID.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how are you calculating the grand total but since `total` is a calculation try to take runnig total for that and print in `grand total`

```
field to be summed: total

Add it for change of group 1 or 2 which one you are using

Reset should be never
```